# grep behavior is odd for NA or "" entries

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and am working with a vector with empty entries and noticed that grep acts counter-intuitively with my data. I'm just going to work with an example as I am not 100% sure how to explain it. Say I have three vectors:

```
A<-c("","","","","","","a")
B<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"a")
```

`A` is how the data was stored originally, and `B` is how R is reading my data. Running `> vec[grep("",vec, invert=TRUE)]` -to my understanding- searches `vec` for all empty cells, return their indices, then populates and displays a result vector with non-empty data entries. However when I run this for `vec=A` and `vec=B` I get:

**vec = A:**

```
> A[grep("",A, invert=FALSE)]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "a" 
> A[grep("",A, invert=TRUE)]
character(0)
```

**vec = B:**

```
> B[grep("",B, invert=FALSE)]
[1] "a"
> B[grep("",B, invert=TRUE)]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Since I thought my data was being read like case B I was stumped by the counter-intuitive result. I realize this could simply be a variable-type issue however I was wondering if someone could shed some more light on the situation as to what is going on.

*quick edit* Case A makes sense: since grep can't find "" because the variable types are off, it returns everything. Inverted, it returns character(0) as the default for "nothing". Still confused by case B.

Comment: If I run `A[grep("",A, invert=FALSE)]` I **do not** get the output you are getting (instead of "NA" I get "", because there are no "NA" in the `A` in your example)

Comment: Oops! that was an earlier iteration of my question. It was supposed to be `[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "a"`. Fixing this now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that `grep` performs **regular expression** searches (not string matching).

The regex `""` that you have fed in is **empty**, so running `grep` asks if any of the strings it is matching against *contains* `""`, not whether the string *entirely matches* "".

For example,

```
grepl("a","bananas")
```

returns `TRUE` because "a" is *in* "bananas".

If you want to match the *entire string* against `""`, you can use '^' and '$' in your regex ('^' means start of string, '$' means end of string):

```
grepl("^$", "") # returns TRUE
grepl("^$", "a") # returns FALSE
```

However you're probably better off not using regex at all if it's just empty cells you want:

```
A[A != ""] # returns "a"
B[!is.na(B)] # returns "a"
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what is at the root of OP's problem, but one possibility to avoid this symptom of grep's behavior, if you *don't* want your dataframe to have empty string entries, is to fill empty cells as NA when you read in from a file.

For example, if reading from a csv:

*df = read.csv(file_name, fill=TRUE, na.strings= "")*

The na.strings argument tells it to read your file in and replace any empty strings with NA.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question:

```
> A[grep("^$", A)]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
> A[grep("^$", A, invert=TRUE)]
[1] "a"
```

Your use of `""` as a pattern is picking up any character element. The use of `"^$"`is picking up the locations of character elements where there are no characters between the beginning and end.

Just as NA does not `"=="` anything (even itself), so to does NA not match `""`.